# Angular devextreme nested popup doesn't work

Tags: angular, popup, devexpress

I have nested template for a pop when hovering over text. However, I can't get it to work. Here is the work:

```
<dx-data-grid
  #dataGrid
  [hoverStateEnabled]="true"
  [dataSource]="killagendaLines"
  (onContextMenuPreparing)="onContextMenuPreparing($event)"
  (onCellClick)="onCellClick($event)"
>
  <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'bookingCellTemplate'">
    <div *ngIf="data.data.BookingStrings.length === 1">
      {{getBookingLabel(data)}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="data.data.BookingStrings.length > 1">
      <a #link>Multiple</a>
      <dx-popover
        target="#link"
        showEvent="mouseenter"
        hideEvent="mouseleave"
        position="top"
        [width]="300"
      >
        <dxo-animation>
          <dxo-show
            type="pop"
            [from]="{ scale: 0 }"
            [to]="{ scale: 1 }"
          ></dxo-show>
          <dxo-hide type="fade" [from]="1" [to]="0"></dxo-hide>
        </dxo-animation>
          <div *dxTemplate="let data = model; of: 'content'">
            {{getBookingLabel(data)}}
          </div>
      </dx-popover>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'item'; let i = index">
    <fa-icon
      *ngIf="data.text === 'Cancel'"
      size="s"
      [icon]="['fas', 'ban']"
    ></fa-icon>
    <span class="dx-icon-{{ data.icon }}"></span>
    <span style="margin-right: 5px"></span>{{ data.text }}
  </div>
</dx-data-grid>
```

Here is screenshot of it:

[image]

Whenever I hover over or click the blue `Multiple` text nothing happens